# Characterizing spectral radius using invertible elements in unital C* algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Consider A a unital C* algebra, I want to show that the spectral radius of a satisfies the following: $()= $ inf$_{∈()}||^{−1}||$, where Inv(A) is the set of invertible elements in A.

So far I can only see one direction, namely $()≤$ inf$_{∈()}||^{−1}||$. I'm wondering how to prove the other direction.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is an exercise in Murphy's book. Where did you come across this, and what's the context in which you need to know the answer?

Comment: Yes this is a problem in Murphy's book. I'm a theoretical physicist and need some knowledge in C* algebra. I got stuck on this problem.

Comment: This question was crossposted on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546121/characterizing-spectral-radius-using-invertible-elements-in-unital-c-algebra.

Comment: By the way I should remark that I don't think this is a trivial question - without the hint given by the first part of the exercise, I remember being stuck on this for a while, a long time ago - but probably MSE is a better home for the question, now that it is getting feedback there.

Comment: I did solve the first part. Now I see the second part. Thank you both very much for the help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was subsequently asked on MSE and got feedback there which led to a resolution